# filter mystery output

Tags: python, list, filter, lambda

I was reading about `filter`, `lambda` and `map`. When I tried using them, I found this peculiarity :

```
def returnAsIs(element):
    return element

print range(10)
print filter(returnAsIs, range(10))
print map(lambda x : x, range(10))

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why is filter omitting the first entry ?

Comment: how you read what `filter` does?

Comment: Please do not add comments into the question. Add them as comments instead. Your question is designated to help others also. Do accept an answer if you feel it has answered your problem and upvote if you feel like. This is the way we express our satisfaction in SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why the element `0` gets skipped in `filter()`?**

This is happening because value `0` evaluates to `False`.

As per the [`.filter()` docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

> Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which **function
>   returns true.**

So, when we apply `filter(function, iterable)` to an `iterable`, only those elements are returned for which the function returns `True`.

When Python iterated over the elements from `0` to `9`, it checks which element evaluates to `True` and only those elements are returned. Now, `0` evaluates to `False` so this value is not returned by `filter()`. Only the elements from `1` to `9` are returned.

**How to check the boolean-ness of an element?**

Since your function is returning the element as it is, we need to check which elements evaluates to `True`. Only those elements will be returned which evaluates to `True`.

To check for the boolean-ness, we can use the [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool)  function.

```
In [1]: for x in range(10):
   ...:     print x, bool(x)
   ...:     
0 False # boolean-ness of '0' is False
1 True
2 True
3 True
4 True
5 True
6 True
7 True
8 True
9 True
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because python treats `0` as False. You can check this out using the function  [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool)

```
>>> bool(0)
False
```

When you read from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter),

> Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns ***true***.

Hence `0` is not returned after the filter function as the value evaluates to `False`. Similar is the case when you have `0` any where in the list

```
>>> print filter(returnAsIs, [1,2,1,0])
[1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter function checks if the value is true or false.
the true values are taken into account and value for which false is returned the values are rejected and on completion a list is returned...
below is better representation

> `filter`(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
>
> Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
>       function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
>       or string, return the same type, else return a list.

Comment: I have edited to make it better so that people themselves will find it useful, instead of you asking for them :)